# R - tidyverse/ggplot bar chart with custom discrete data labels and sorted by one variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a data frame with which I am learning `tidyverse` methods in R that looks like this:

```
> glimpse(data)
Observations: 16
Variables: 6
$ True.species  <fct> Badger, Blackbird, Brown hare, Domestic cat, Domestic d...
$ misidentified <dbl> 17, 16, 59, 20, 12, 24, 28, 6, 3, 7, 191, 19, 110, 21, ...
$ missed        <dbl> 61, 106, 7, 24, 16, 160, 110, 12, 15, 37, 200, 58, 259,...
$ Total         <dbl> 78, 122, 66, 44, 28, 184, 138, 18, 18, 44, 391, 77, 369...
$ PrMissed      <dbl> 0.7820513, 0.8688525, 0.1060606, 0.5454545, 0.5714286, ...
$ PrMisID       <dbl> 0.21794872, 0.13114754, 0.89393939, 0.45454545, 0.42857...
```

Here is the `dput()`:

```
data <- structure(list(True.species = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 13L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L), .Label = c("Badger", 
"Blackbird", "Brown hare", "Crow", "Domestic cat", "Domestic dog", 
"Grey squirrel", "Hedgehog", "Horse", "Human", "Jackdaw", "Livestock", 
"Magpie", "Muntjac", "Nothing", "Pheasant", "Rabbit", "Red fox", 
"Red squirrel", "Roe Deer", "Small rodent", "Stoat or Weasel", 
"Woodpigeon"), class = "factor"), misidentified = c(17, 16, 59, 
20, 12, 24, 28, 6, 3, 7, 191, 19, 110, 21, 5, 13), missed = c(61, 
106, 7, 24, 16, 160, 110, 12, 15, 37, 200, 58, 259, 473, 9, 17
), Total = c(78, 122, 66, 44, 28, 184, 138, 18, 18, 44, 391, 
77, 369, 494, 14, 30), PrMissed = c(0.782051282051282, 0.868852459016393, 
0.106060606060606, 0.545454545454545, 0.571428571428571, 0.869565217391304, 
0.797101449275362, 0.666666666666667, 0.833333333333333, 0.840909090909091, 
0.51150895140665, 0.753246753246753, 0.70189701897019, 0.95748987854251, 
0.642857142857143, 0.566666666666667), PrMisID = c(0.217948717948718, 
0.131147540983607, 0.893939393939394, 0.454545454545455, 0.428571428571429, 
0.130434782608696, 0.202898550724638, 0.333333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 
0.159090909090909, 0.48849104859335, 0.246753246753247, 0.29810298102981, 
0.0425101214574899, 0.357142857142857, 0.433333333333333)), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = "data.frame")
```

I managed to make a rudimentary plot of what I want with `ggplot()` as follows:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = True.species, y = PrMissed)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

But there are three things I can't figure out how to do:

1. I want a stacked bar chart where the variables `PrMissed` and `PrMisID` are on top of each other. Note that `PrMissed + PrMisID == 1` for each row in the data frame, so the final plot would have equally high stacks but each containing two colors (how do I specify them?), one for `PrMissed` and another for `PrMisID`.
2. I want the order of the bars to be in ascending order of the `PrMissed` variable so that `Brown hare` would be on one end and `Small rodent` on the other.
3. I prefer this plot to be "flipped" on its side so that the labels (the animal names like "Brown hare") are on the left side and easier to read. An added complexity is that rather than the labels simply saying the animal name, I want them to say the corresponding `Total` value, so for example `Brown hare` would get a corresponding axis label like "Brown hare (total = 66)".

I been trying for a long time a for the life of me couldn't figure out an axiomatic way to do this with `ggplot()`. I know the answer might be simple so please excuse my ignorance. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my answer which does not require the use of `data.tables` and is solely based on `tidyverse` packages:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
# order Species by PrMissed value 
data$True.species <- factor(data$True.species,
                        levels = data[order(data$PrMissed, decreasing = F),"True.species"])

# reshape to have the stackable values and plot
melt(data,
 id.vars = c("True.species", "misidentified", "missed", "Total"),
 measure.vars = c("PrMissed", "PrMisID")) %>%
 mutate(x_axis_text = paste(.$True.species, "(Total = ",  .$Total, ")") ) %>%  
   ggplot(aes(x = x_axis_text, y = value, fill = variable) ) +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
   coord_flip()
```

Which would result in a plot like this

[image]

**Break down of the code**: 
Your individual points are done like this.

1) To have stackable values, they need to be all in one column, so using `melt` from the `reshape2` package we tidy the data and create 2 new columns in the `data`. One is `value` containing the values from 0 to 1 and the other is `variable` indicating if that number is associated with `PrMissed` or `PrMisID`

2) Before `melt`ing the data we convert the `True.species` values into factor based on `PrMissed` values. Use `decreasing = T` to invert the order if you wish.

3) `coord_flip()` flips the x and y axis so that the species are on the y axis instead of the y axis and you can easily read them on the left side.

Comment: Oooh, thanks so much this is super informative! :D Two nit-picky questions: (1) What if I want to display the `Total` values as part of the animals names for the axis labels (i.e. "Brown hare (total = 66)") instead of on top of the bars? Is the only way to do this to `mutate()` a new variable (before `melt()`ing) that combines `True.species` and `Total` into a string (which is then converted to factors for use in the plot)? (2) Is there a way to specify custom colors for the bars?

Comment: Point (1): you can add this after the first pipe operator (`%>%`) `mutate(x_axis_text = paste(.$True.species, "(Total = ",  .$Total, ")") )`. `Mutate` from `dplyr` packages is used to create a new column callex `x_axis_label` that is formed by `paste`ing characters. I don't know if using `mutate` is the only way to achieve this but is probably the easiest. After that you just need to change the x-axis variable in the `aes` to `x = x_axis_text`.

Point(2) read  the documentation [here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html)

Comment: Thanks! Both your (1) & (2) makes sense. That said, your example output above is not in order of `PrMissed`... Should I turn the newly-created `x_axis_text` into an ordered set of factors before calling `ggplot()`?

Answer (score 1):

I can help with a `data.table` and `ggplot2` solution:

First, you'll need to make your wide table a long one with `melt`. Then, you're looking for `position = "stack"` argument to `geom_bar`:

Also, please notice that naming `data` a table is bad idea, as there's a function called `data()`.

```
require(data.table)
ggplot(melt(df[, .(True.species, PrMissed, PrMisID)], 
            id.vars="True.species"), 
       aes(x = True.species, y = value, fill = variable))+
   geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity")
```

I forgot about the sorting... (and rotation of texts, so they are readable):

```
ggplot(melt(df[, .(True.species, PrMissed, PrMisID)], 
            id.vars="True.species"), 
       aes(x = True.species, y = value, 
           fill = variable))+
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))+
  scale_x_discrete(limits = sort(df$True.species))
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Just to confirm: `df[, .(True.species, PrMissed, PrMisID)]` is the part that uses `data.table`, right? If I want to use `tidyverse` am I correct that I can probably use `select()` for this purpose?

Comment: @hpy Yes, that and `melt` are the parts that use `data.table`. You can replace `melt` by any of the wide to long functions of the reshape, reshape2 or tidyverse packages